# Patch needed to fix bouncing cursor on HP laptop

Tags: laptop, hp

This question MIGHT not be related to Ubuntu, but it may, so...

I own an HP laptop where the whole area in front of the keyboard is a tracker. That means I have to type very carefully lest an errant move sends the cursor to some other part of the screen. When I was on Windows I found some little patch that solved the issue. That seems to be gone now with my switch to Ubuntu. Does anyone know of a similar solution?

Comment: have you tried [this](https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/how-to-disable-the-touchpad-while-you-are-typing/) ?

Comment: Thank you...this is intriguing. However, I can't find the file the solution mentions, /etc/x11/xorg.conf. It is probably another file I need to mod, so I  will investigate.